# Child-routes not cached by keep-alive

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router, keep-alive

I am wrapping my router with a keep-alive like so:

```
<template>
  <section class="app-main">
    <keep-alive :include="['TopLevelRoute', 'ChildRoute']">
      <router-view :key="key" />
    </keep-alive>
  </section>
</template>
```

Now, my TopLevelRoute is always cached nicely. My ChildRoute on the other hand is never cached. Both components are named components with the names spelled correctly and passed correctly to the include.

Here are my routes:

```
children: [
    {
      children: [
        {
          component: ChildRoute,
          meta: {
            title: 'ChildRoute'
          },
          name: 'ChildRoute',
          path: 'child-route'
        },
        // more child-components here
      ],
      component: Info,
      meta: { title: 'Info' },
      name: 'Info',
      path: 'info',
      redirect: 'noRedirect'
    },
    {
      component: TopLevelRoute,
      meta: {
        title: 'TopLevelRoute'
      },
      name: 'TopLevelRoute',
      path: 'top-level-route'
    },
    // more child-components here
  ],
  component: Account,
  meta: {
    icon: 'id',
    title: 'Account'
  },
  name: 'Account',
  path: '/account',
  redirect: 'noRedirect'
}
```

I think the problem stems from `ChildRoute` being in the `children`-Array of `Info`. If I pull `ChildRoute` out of `children` and put it on the same level as `TopLevelRoute`, it is cached just fine.

The routing itself works seamlessly - just the caching is not on my side right now.

I saw a lot of similar questions, but never this specific case, so I hope this is not a duplicate question.

Thank you in advance for your help! I am pretty desperate right now.

Comment: Could you please give more info about your problem? For example what is ```key``` data or how you could define your route in ```router.js```.  As I could guess **ChildRoute** is the child of ```info``` route not ```TopLevelRoute```.

Comment: @hamid-davodi - Hi! That's right. `ChildRoute` is the child of `Info`. `TopLevelRoute` is on the same level as `Info`. 
The key data I pass to the router-view is the full path of the current route.

Answer (score 0):

As you did not posted the codes related to your `router.js` and your views, I post the codes related to my views and `router.js` file that you can test in your local environment to see that it caches `ChildRoute` states. To test that I used an `input` tag with a `v-model`. Here is the code of `router.js`:

> router.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';
import Search from "../views/Search";
import ChildRoute from "../views/ChildRoute"


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/Search/ChildRoute',
    name: 'ChildRoute',
    component: ChildRoute
  },
  {
    path: '/Search',
    name: 'Search',
    component: Search
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

Here is the code of `App.vue` that has the navigation and `router-view` inside it:

> App.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/search">Search</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/search/childroute">ChildRoute</router-link> |
    </div>
    <section class="app-main">
      <keep-alive :include="['About', 'ChildRoute']">
        <router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
      </keep-alive>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

And finally the codes related to each route has the similar structure like this:

> ChildRoute.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>ChildRoute component</h1>
    <input type="text" v-model="chachedData">
    <!-- other html tags ... -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ChildRoute",
  data() {
    return {
      chachedData: ""
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

If you test it you can see that the input `v-model` state is cached in `About.vue` and `ChildRoute.vue`, but not in `Home.vue`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for trying to help me. I have updated my question above to clarify my problem. Your code works just fine. I think the problem might come from the `children` array of my route. The children are not cached.

Comment: @McMuellermilch, If the ```children``` option that you use in your ```router.js``` is the one that [vue router documentation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) says, then you must use a separate ```router-view``` in child views to see the contents. So you can not expect that ```router-view``` also be cached. Maybe you need to use another ```<keep-alive>``` in that child component templates to cache the content correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I will play around with another `<keep-alive>`. Thank you for your help though! :)